# Should bower_components be included into the project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, bower

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that was initially using Nuget for static content like Bootstrap, jQuery etc. I have now switched to bower as it is the way to go and is also integrated with visual studio.

I noticed that when installing bower packages, they are not automatically included into the project. So I have left them out for now but is this a good idea? Should bower packages be included or not? It doesn't make any difference to access because in my `BundleConfig.cs` file I'm still able to link these files to aliases as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bower will download the entire package using Git.

> Your package must be publically available at a Git endpoint (e.g., GitHub). Remember to push your Git tags!

This means that bower will actually download the entire repository/release for you to use in your ASP project. I've tested this with bootstrap and jQuery. These repositories can contain many many files so including them into the `.csproj` file will clutter your project file and may not be ideal.

This can be compared to using nuget packages where we are only referencing external packages in the `packages.config` file but we do not include the `dll` and other assemblies into the project. This leads me to think that `bower_components` should indeed not be included in the project; this makes no difference to usage as you can still reference the packages and use the files.